# How to upgrade Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8.1 while keeping data in D and E drives?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1

I downloaded a Windows 8.1 `.iso` file and made a virtual drive using Virtual CloneDrive and mounted it. I want to upgrade my Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8.1 while keeping the data in D and E partitions. I do not want any data in C partition. I ran the setup using the virtual drive and it asks me what to keep.
It gives me only two options that is,

- Keep personal files only
- Keep nothing

There is no option to keep data in D and E partitions. I read the meaning of personal files on microsoft website and it states that personal files means only the thing in my user folder. So i want to upgrade Windows by keeping D and E partitions and I do not want data in C partition.

Answer (score 1):

Your user account folder is located at C:/Users/[Your Profile Name] (aka C Partition). It contains the Documents, Downloads, Music, Videos, etc folders that are located on C partition unless you changed it's location.

By default when you are upgrading windows the data in partitions other than C partition is kept as is.

If you select :
1. Keep personal files only : The data in user account folder will be retained along with the data in D and E paritions.
2. Keep nothing : The data in user account folder will be lost but the data in D and E partitions will be retained.

In either option the data in partitions other than C will not be lost when upgrading.